# Amazon Lex's session attributes do not allow nested object?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am trying to persist a nested object in `sessionAttributes`. However, it seems Amazon Lex does not recognize if I send a structure like this in response:

```
{
    "sessionAttributes": {
        "previousIntent": "TCAIntent",
        "prevSlots": {
            "test": 1
        }
    },
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Delegate",
        "slots": {
            "firstName": null,
            "lastName": null,
            "rate": null,
            "rentMortgage": null,
            "downPayment": null,
            "purchasePrice": null,
            "email": null
        }
    }
}
```

When I replace `{"test": 1}` with a value, it works fine. Is there a way around this or possible mistake?

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out that Lex does not allow storing json object or array on `sessionAttributes`. As a work around, I converted the json object to string and convert it back when I need to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Come across the question figuring out the same sort of problem

Comment: Perfect! This did not throw an error for me (at least no where I could access) and it took a week to narrow it down to this being the problem/solution.